# C++: how to check whether an external program is running?

Tags: python, c++, windows, external-process, process-management

I run an external program with C++:

```
_wsystem(exec);
```

I want to kill the process if it runs for more than n seconds. I can do it in Python like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(self.temp_exec, shell=True)

cur_time = 0.0

while cur_time < self.time_limit:
            if p.poll() != None:
                # Kill the process
                                    p.terminate()
                break
            time.sleep(0.1)
            cur_time += 0.1
```

What's the alternative of p.poll() and p.terminate() in C++?

Thank you

P.S. Solutions involving WinAPI are welcome too.

Comment: Which platform are you using? Unlike Python (which abstracts these operations for you in a semi-portable way), in C, each operating system does it differently.

Comment: Bummer, I don't know Windows well enough to help you there. But I posted a Unix answer, anyway. :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [MS knowledge base entry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178893) describing how to cleanly terminate applications. Essentially if you just want to kill the process and don't care about potential side effects then you can just use `TerminateProcess`.

The Windows API way to check if a process is still running is `GetExitCodeProcess`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can resolve this issue on the OS level and not using Python. E.g. might look into

http://devel.ringlet.net/sysutils/timelimit/

Or you man check the resource module of Python:

http://docs.python.org/library/resource.html

Answer (score 0):

I can only comment on Unix, since that's the platform I know best.

- `p.poll()` becomes `kill(pid, 0)`
- `p.terminate()` becomes `kill(pid, SIGTERM)`

Comment: Thanks anyway, this might be useful in the future :)